# Error installing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

The installer is made in Visual Studio 2010 (setup project). It is random which dll that it fails on.

> Error writing to file: filename.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory.

It works on Windows 7 (x64) sometimes, if I rebuild it it might not work.

This error appears in Windows XP x86 install.

The log did not make more sense to me:

> MSI (s) (B0:0C) [14:03:19:342]: Note: 1: 1304 2: filename.dll
>
> MSI (s) (B0:0C) [14:03:19:342]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
>
> MSI (c) (54:50) [14:03:19:342]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
>
> DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog,

Comment: You'll have to give more detail.

Comment: Turns out that a team member had updated a component we use. Therefor the dll's we had put in the GAC and linked to in the installer where wrong. The reason I didn't seen this was that it where just a service release and had just a minor version number change. We solved it by examine the msi.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of Error Codes:

http://desktopengineer.com/msierrors

Your error code 2835 translates to **The control [2] was not found on dialog [3]**.